# can't change my table data in angulars?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

i posted a question before but no answer, maybe my code was too long, so i am having this problem, i have a table :

```
$scope.slides = [
   {"status":true},
   {"status":false},
   {"status":false},
]
```

when i try to get the value of the first element or second or third element it works by using this :

```
 var i = $scope.slides[0].status //1,2 for second and third
 alert(i) // it works fine
```

but i want this data to change every second :

```
 $scope.change = $interval(function($scope){
   if(condition){
      $scope.slides[0].status = false
    }else {
      $scope.slides[0].status = true
  }
   })
```

I am puuting this value in my HTML in the ng-show directive, it seems         nothing is changing ..

Thank you

Comment: I think it is not working, because you introduced `$scope` as argument of function passed to `$interval` service, and so hide actual `$scope`. Try to simply eliminate it : `$scope.change = $interval(function(){...});`

Comment: oooooh True true! i solved my problem with an other solution but now i have two solution to the same problem wich is beautiful! thank you so much friend!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your objects to json. Currently they are stringified.

You need to do something like:

```
for(var i=0; i<=$scope.slides.length; i++){
    $scope.slides[i] = JSON.parse($scope.slides[i]);
}
```

Then whatever you are doing above, should work.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle or plunkr with the code please? :) It'd be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In theory this should work:

```
$scope.change = $interval(function(){
   //change between true and false every second.
   $scope.slides[0].status = !$scope.slides[0].status;
}, 1000); //1000 ms, 1s
```

Comment: In theory both should work Hahahaha! they re not both working .. it seems like when the programs finds this instruction ( $scope.slides[0].status = !$scope.slides[0].status; ) it leaves the function and rexecute again without reading what is above this instruction :( ..